# How far north from Vancouver can you get by train?

Tags: trains, canada, vancouver, british-columbia

If I start in Vancouver, there are certainly trains heading east and north (and south).  What I want to know is how far north I can get using just trains, if I start in Vancouver, BC?  And are they running during all seasons?

Comment: As far as I can remember from a TV documentary, ferry is also a great way of going north from Seattle or Vancouver.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Pacific route is a beautiful route! Expensive, but beautiful none the less.

> From the West Coast of the U.S., you can take Amtrak's Cascades train 
>       (tel. 800/USA RAIL; www.amtrak.com) to Bellingham, Washington; the dock 
>       for the Alaska ferry is quite close to the railroad station. From the east, it 
>       makes more sense to use Canada's Via Rail (tel. 888/VIA-RAIL; www.viarail.ca). The
>       transcontinental route starts all the way back in Toronto; you change in Jasper 
>       to end up in Prince Rupert, B.C., where you can catch the Alaska ferry north.

[Read more](http://www.frommers.com/destinations/alaska/0210020009.html#ixzz1htRQFs76)

Regardless, your [prognosis is not good](http://www.viarail.ca/en/trains/rockies-and-pacific/jasper-prince-rupert/schedules); you'll have to double back East to head North, and you'll only go as far as Prince Rupert. (Screenshot from www.viarail.ca)

[image: Via BC map]

I would go with if I didn't have a job! `:D`

Comment: There's also a ferry from Prince Rupert down to Vancouver Island - although it doesn't dock as far south as Courtenay, or you could do a round trip with just train and ferry!

Comment: The Rocky Mountaineer does the Northern route as well, if I'm not mistaken through Whistler and North... but obviously that's more of an expensive tourist train and you'd have to get off in Quesnel.

Answer (score -1):

There is a train running north west from Prince George up toward Nations Lakes.

Comment: Can you please give more information, like a link to a website, and a quote from that website?